# Boot image did not Authenticate

Tags: boot, uefi, bootable-media

I am having trouble while booting Live Kali Linux from USB. I created the image on Ubuntu and then I was trying to boot it. Here is what I get:

> Selected boot image did not Authenticate. Press Enter to Continue.

I have HP Pavilion x360 Convertible, bios version: f.16.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should make sure "Secure Boot" is turned off, otherwise no "unauthorized" OS will be able to boot: the EFI just rejects it.